# Google Admin SDK - Users: Patch - Issue using Strings

Tags: patch, google-admin-sdk, vcf-vcard

i have an issue using the Users: Patch - API.
I try to patch the name of the primary organization of a user using the following Request Body:

```
{
"organizations":[
    {
     "name":"Org. Name",
     "primary":true,
     "type":work
    }
]
}
```

The values of the users entry get patched, but the result looks like:

```
{
"organizations":[
    {
    "name": "\"Org. Name\"",
    "primary": true,
    "type": "work"
    }
]
}
```

The problem: the VCard entry of the user shows "Org. Name" instead of Org. Name as it should.

Is it possible to prevent the string getting formatted as a string again by the API?

Thank you for your help!

Lukas

Comment: That's unexpected. It would be helpful I think if you added the code necessary to create a [minimal  and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: @PeterHerrmann I just experienced the same thing when using the "try it" functionality on [https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update](the API documentation page], as well as when using a php script to do so. Posting a body of `{ "organizations": [{ "title": "Senior Developer" }] }` becomes "\"Senior Developer\"" in the resulting postback.

Comment: @MueR I can reproduce this too. This appears to be a bug. You can log bugs on the Apps API issue tracker here: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list

Comment: @MueR I logged this as a bug here: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5080 Please "star" it to follow progress.